# Export csv file in .net web app

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-csv

I have already saved csv file as /Exports/test.csv. I want to allow user to download file on button click . I have create a handler for that code is as :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Downloadfile" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

public class Downloadfile : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
            "attachment; filename=" + context.Request.QueryString["file"]);

        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code download the file but its empty. I want just download csv file with its content.

Comment: So your response header says there is a file in the response, but you don't actually send the file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to transmit file. You can do that by using [TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) method or instead of write to disk you can just write directly to `context.Response.OutputStream`.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +  context.Request.QueryString["file"]);
    context.Response.TransmitFile("/Exports/test.csv");
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: it works what show the downloaded file content as:  ‹      I-.QÈMÌÓQ±Âól š÷Æ   and actual is "Test man, Test Woman"

Answer (score 3):

I actually had to do the same thing the other day, depending on what the users pass in the "Accepts" header. I used the example from the [MSDN article on Media Formatters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters), and it worked perfectly.

Mine was a bit different from yours since I'm using MVC's WebApi, but the underlying concepts are the same.